# Non-ordinary differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

Does such a thing exist?

Can't seem to find anything about it so I was wondering, why bother calling something "Ordinary Differential Equation" (ODE) if the *Ordinary* part doesn't bring anything to it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's called an "[ordinary differential equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation)" because it involves a function (or functions) of *one* independent variable and normal (i.e. not partial) derivatives, whereas a "[partial differential equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation)" involves functions of multiple independent variables and partial derivatives.

For example,
$$
y' + 2xy = 3x
$$
is an ordinary differential equation (the independent variable being x), and
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0
$$
is a partial differential equation (the multiple independent variables being $x$ and $y$).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 8):

"Ordinary" is in contrast with "Partial" as is "Partial Differential Equations" or PDE

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what others have already said, there are other types of differential equation.

There's the Stochastic Differential Equation, which contain random elements.

There's the Differential-difference equation, which is a blending of differential and difference equations, such as

$$
\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=f(x-1)
$$

So an ordinary differential equation is a differential equation that doesn't have anything "special" about it, it's just a differential equation. It is, quite literally, ordinary.